# How to test that DNS from NIS is working?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, centos, nis

In my `/etc/nsswitch.conf` have I set

```
hosts: files nis dns
```

With

```
ypwhich
ypcat hosts
ypcat passwd
```

can I verify that `passwd` and `group` are retrieved over NIS.

**Question**

How do I verify that DNS is working in NIS, as `ping` gets it DNS from `/etc/resolve.conf` and not NIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally `ping` and other commands to need host name resolving are linked to libc and should follow the order you demanded in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and use /etc/hosts and NIS before resolving to dns.

`nslookup` and `dig` always consult DNS and never use the entries in /etc/hosts or NIS.

`getent hosts <hostname | ip-address>` will use the C resolver functions, honours nsswitch.conf and will show entries from your hosts file or the NIS directory before trying dns to lookup that hostname or ip-address